# Why does order matter when using Perl switches -nle in a one liner?

Tags: perl

If I do -nle I get a different result than -len.  Example: `echo ham | perl  -nle ' m/^h(.{2})/ ; print "$& and $1"'
output: ham and am`
 but the same line with -len gives me no output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `e` means "That which follows is a line of the script".

If you follow the `e` with an `n` then that is what you are trying to evaluate.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I guess I assumed it had enough logic to differentiate switches from the actual command.  Also, n isn't a command (is it?)so why don't I get a compile error?

Comment: You haven't got `use strict;` so you can have [barewords](http://perlmaven.com/barewords-in-perl).